# cannot wordpress admin login with disabled wordfence

Tags: wordpress, multisite, wordpress-admin, wordfence

i have multisite wordpress (version 5.7.2) with wordfence plugins installed.
after several days not logged in i found email notification from wordfence reported that people try login using admin account but unsuccessful.

i try to login by myself too and unsuccessful. so i rename wordfence plugin folder to disable it.

i successfully logged in using admin account from subsite (sub.mainsite.com) but not from main site (mainsite.com). and i cannot access network admin menu in mainsite.

my question is, how to be able to re-access main site using admin account?

Comment: Do you have server access?

Comment: yes i do. i can access mysql too.

Comment: Go to wp-content/plugins folder and rename wordfence folder to like wordfence-bk for temprory.

Comment: i did it. as i told in my description, after rename wordfence plugins folder, i successfully logged in from subsite/wp-admin, but not from mainsite/wp-admin.

Comment: what error site gives you when you tried to log in?

Comment: it doesn't show any error message. it just return to login form.

Comment: Then I think you need to debug a little.

Comment: i've tried to enabling debug with these lines

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`

but nothing show in debug.log.

Comment: I think you need to debug another way. because it does not look like a code issue.

Comment: Can anyone give the initial step instructions out of this case?

Answer (score 0):

do you use cache plugins? try to purge cache.
or clear browser cache.
try to access wp-admin using another browser.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete Wordfence, .htaccess and user.ini files and set up it again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).